# How to include resource file into osgi bundle from jar dependency with bnd/maven-bundle-plugin?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm using `maven-bundle-plugin` (`bnd` effectively).

It's straightforward to include a resource file from sources.

For example, a resource file (`src/main/resources/some.xml`) is moved under `target` directory (`target/classes/some.xml`) during build time and can be included into the bundle using `<Include-Resource>` instruction:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Include-Resource>
                some.xml=target/classes/some.xml,
            </Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Let us have a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**How to reference resource file inside dependent `jar`?**

In other words, how to

- specify something like this:

  ```
  com.example:library:1.0.0:jar/some.xml
  ```
- instead of this:

  ```
  target/classes/some.xml
  ```

so that resource from one of the dependency appeared in output bundle `jar`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to reference some.xml at runtime from code inside the bundle?

Comment: I just want to package bundle `jar` with `some.xml` taken from inside of another (dependency) `jar`. Ultimately, this will be referenced by code, but before it can be referenced by code, it should be packaged into output `jar`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to un-compress your dependencies jar and then include the resource in your jar.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <markersDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies/dependency-maven-plugin-markers</markersDirectory>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>DEPENDENCY_GROUPID</groupId>
                        <artifactId>DEPENDENCY_ARTIFACTID</artifactId>
                        <type>OPTIONAL_DEPENCENCY_TYPE</type>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies/DEPENDENCY_ARTIFACTID</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <instructions>
            ...
            <Include-Resource>target/dependencies/DEPENDENCY_ARTIFACTID/some.xml</Bundle-Activator>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `Include-Resource` instructions is supposed to be pom relative, see [Include-Resource](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#include-resource), you can probably replace `target`with `${project.build.directory}`.

Comment: Honestly, I expected there could be a trick from `maven-bundle-plugin`/`bnd` to select resources to be moved into output bundle `jar` similarly as the plugin does when `Private-Package` instruction specified with packages (and these packages become part of the output bundle `jar`). However, this answer is straightforward and goes around by cutting off some responsibilities from the sophistication of `maven-bundle-plugin`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a file reference to the jar, you can do

`-includeresource: @path/to/file.jar!/some.xml`

You use the `@` prefix to say the resource is in the jar and the `!/` syntax from jar urls.

The tricky part will be getting a path to the jar from the project dependencies I suspect.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know how to reliably reference copy of the `jar` file which is listed as Maven dependency. So, the answer with `maven-dependency-plugin` was acceptable and fixed the problem for now. However, I might need your piece of information too - upvoting. Thanks!

Comment: For more info, you can get a path to a jar using the (I think undocumented) `repo` macro, e.g:
`-includeresource: @${repo;org.apache.felix.http;latest}!/META-INF/LICENSE`
You can even do things like this (but not in the cnf project as I guess the repos haven't been defined yet):
`-include: jar:${fileuri;${repo;bsn;version}}!/resource.properties`

Comment: This question is about a maven build, so their is no bnd workspace and so it is unlikely any repos are configured for the repo macro to be of any use.

Comment: Oh dear, right you are! I just came from Google with my slightly related problem without properly understanding the context. Well, hopefully it will help someone out all the same.